# How to query through the JSON array inside JSON object in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

This is the JSON structure I have in the table column:

```
{  
   "roles":[  
      {  
         "role_id":1,
         "permissions":1
      },
      {  
         "role_id":2,
         "permissions":2
      },
      {  
         "role_id":3,
         "permissions":3
      }
   ],
   "user_groups":[  
      {  
         "permissions":2,
         "user_group_id":123
      },
      {  
         "permissions":3,
         "user_group_id":1234
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to query the list **roles** key and map the **role_id** in the query. Jow can I achieve this using MySQL?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, How can I achieve this using MySQL?

Comment: Can you give an example of the result you expect?.